# Reverse columns order

Tags: css

I need a fixed green element in the top right corner.

I tried flex elements, but it works only with elements with the same height, otherwise, I have empty space between rows

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  columns: 3;
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.item.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item green">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean top right or top left corner? Right now, it's top left.

Comment: Please clarify further your desired end result

Comment: Like this https://jsbin.com/soxibal/edit?html,css,output but without empty space.

Comment: https://wireframe.cc/zbeqHC Here is image. Red element always should be in top right corner

Comment: The overall layout that you want seems clear. However, having the items show up in "uneven" rows as you show in your jsbin example is a bit peculiar. Do you care about the layout of B through G, whether by row or column?

Comment: You should use `grid` instead of `flex` for this particular output.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't providing a little more structure in your HTML? The reason for not doing so would be if you want the flow to change depending upon screen size, but those needs haven't been expressed in your question. For example, you could just create 3 div or grid columns and designate explicitly what you want in each column. It's not clear whether the location of B through G is fixed, or whether you need it to automatically adjust depending...

Comment: I tried to build a minimal example. I'll try the grid. I think it will be fine